# Know if apple account has done trial before?

Tags: ios, swift, subscription, trial

Is there any way to know if a user has already trial subscribed previously on my app with his current logged apple id account?

I want to know that so I can no longer offer a trial for a user which has already done some trial with this apple id account.

Comment: Do you have a login system for each user ??

Comment: Yes, but i also want to know if this apple id account has subscribed to a trial before independently from which login it is using.

Comment: Are you using IAP? What sort? Non consumable or auto renewing subscription?

Comment: I'm using auto renewing.

Comment: If you are using an auto-renewing subscription with a free trial, then Apple will automatically bill the person as soon as they restart a subscription if they have previously used the free trial.

Comment: You can also look through the in-app purchase history in the IAP receipt and look free-trial subscriptions